# Creating an image on load of SVG editor

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I am working on svg editor, specifically the Method draw implementantion.

I want on loading the editor to load an image instead of a background rectangle. Currently the javascript file includes this command to create a background rectangle within the editor.

```
var createBackground = function(fill) {
    svgCanvas.createLayer("background")
        cur_shape = svgCanvas.addSvgElementFromJson({
            "element": "rect",
            "attr": {

                "x": -1,
                "y": -1,
                "width": res.w+2,
                "height": res.h+2,
                "stroke": "none",
                "id": "canvas_background",
                "opacity": 1,
                "fill":  '#ffffff',
                "style": "pointer-events:none"
```

I want to create an image instead of a rectangle.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the function like this:

```
var createBackground = function(fill) {
    svgCanvas.createLayer("background")
        cur_shape = svgCanvas.addSvgElementFromJson({
            "element": "image",
            "attr": {
                "x": -1,
                "y": -1,
                "width": res.w+2,
                "height": res.h+2,
                "xlink:href": "/images/whatever.png" //this path should be changed
                "id": "canvas_background",
                "opacity": 1,
                "style": "pointer-events:none"
```

Comment: thanks mark! ive sent you an email 2 weeks ago but i guess you are too busy! thanks a lot man appreciate it. I got it to work yesterday on my own. Problem is when you coded the application with the create rectabgle background i was able to get a "reference" rectangle so that i know when my users draw outside their viewbox since i was able to get the rectangle background throught the output. Now with the image because i dont get it in the output(its not embedded with the drawing) i dont have something to show me the workarea that my user selected. Any ideas?